# Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RAP'

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have an application (Azure Service Fabric) that works successfully locally and on environment with 3 nodes but on environment with 5 nodes two services contain warning (for one of the 5 replicas):

```
Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RAP', Property='IStatelessServiceInstance.OpenDuration', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
```

As a result sometimes we get `503 Service Unavailable Error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed with redeploy of Azure Service Fabric.